# How to store more than one string in jList

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

how can i represent more than one string line code, for instance if i have made a jlist and used String to duplicate the value stored in the string to appear on a Jtextfield can i create another string line to show the movie price in another Jtextfield whilst the jList value is selected for example: in Jlist i have selected a component it will show the component in a Jtextfield and the price in another jTextfield?

```
    jList99.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {

        String[] strings = {"mouse,keyboard"};
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jList99.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
            jList1ValueChanged(evt);        
        }
    });


private void jList1ValueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {     

     if(!jList99.getValueIsAdjusting())
     { 
          jTextField9.setText((String) jList99.getSelectedValue());
     }
}
```

Comment: For a simple solution, you could wrap your String HTML

Answer (score 2):

Your JList doesn't have to contain a simple String object.  You can achieve your goal by using a custom object such as this:

```
class MovieInfo {
    private String name;
    private String price;

    // insert appropriate getters and setters here

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + price;
    }
}
```

Those object will display their toString value in the JList, but you'll have direct access to the name and price when you call (MovieInfo)getSelectedValue().